# How to install Arial font or any true type font in Debian Wheezy?

Tags: linux, debian-wheezy, font

I have a web page deployed in server linux (Wheezy server version) and this web page generate a PDF file using a Arial font. I've looked at:

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/
```

and there is no Arial font found there, only:

```
DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf
DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf
DejaVuSansMono.ttf
DejaVuSans.ttf
DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf
DejaVuSerif.ttf
```

How to install Arial font?

Comment: PS: The command apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer, don't works

Comment: Doesn't work how?  Did you make sure you had the contrib repo enabled?

Comment: Yes, i added this contrib in sources.list :deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian  main contrib     and after, i used aptitude update

Comment: i've tested in Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop . Works fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solve the problem with:

```
wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/contrib/m/msttcorefonts/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb

#Dependence for dpkg 
apt-get install cabextract 

#Install fonts by dpkg
dpkg -i ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb

reboot
```

After this the report works fine.

Comment: It really ought to work to just add contrib to the regular sources as per https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Example_sources.list though

Answer (score 0):

Linux does not include the Arial font by default for licensing reasons, as it is a Microsoft font, but we can install it as follows:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

To complete the installation of this package, we must agree to the licence terms:

[image]

Not always, but sometimes we also need to rebuild in addition a new font information cache file on the system:

```
sudo fc-cache -vr
```

After this, the Arial font should be available on our system:

```
fc-list | grep Arial
```

[Source](https://linuxhint.com/ttf-mscorefonts-installer/)